# Vuex Two-Way computed property with Arrays or nested data?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Is it possible to use [two-way computed property](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property) in vuex with an array?

Example: I have an array of questions and each question can be edited at the same time. I would like to do the following

```
<div v-for="question in getQuestions(sectionId)">
    <input type="text" v-model="question.title" />
</div>
```